# canvasjs x-axis label shows y-axis index in combined chart

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I am using Canvasjs combined chart type for showing 2 y-axis value against single x-axis value(time). But as you can see in the image, x-axis label showing y-axis's index label in particular case.

[image]

If you see, instead of 10:00 AM it is showing "Gold Coast" in the chart.

I tried setting the interval for x-axis like below but nothing worked for me.

```
axisX: {
    //interval: 1,
    intervalType: "hour",
    //valueFormatString: "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"
},
```

What could be the issue and and any idead how to resolve that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var location_datapoints = [
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 10, 0), y: 4, indexLabel: "Gold Coast", indexLabelOrientation: "vertical", label: "Gold Coast" },
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 11, 0), y: 4, indexLabel: "Mount Tambrine", indexLabelOrientation: "vertical", label: "Gold Coast" }
];
var workrest_datapoints = [
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 10, 0), y: 2, label: "Work" },
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 11, 0), y: 1, label: "Rest" }
];
   //console.log(location_datapoints);
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 exportEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "Driver Work Rest Data"
 },
 axisY:{ 
  title: "Work or Rest",
  includeZero: false,
  interval: 1,
  labelFormatter: function ( e ) {
   var ret;
   switch(e.value){
    case 1:
     ret = "Rest";
     break;
    case 2:
     ret = "Work";
     break;
    case 3:
     ret = "2-up";
     break;
    case 4:
     ret = "Location";
     break;
    case 5:
     ret = "Comments";
     break;
    case 6:
     ret = "Annotations"
     break;
    default:
     ret = '';
   }
            return ret;  
        }
 },
 axisX: {
   //interval: 1,
   intervalType: "hour",
   //valueFormatString: "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"
   },
 data: [
 
  {
   type: "bubble",
   //toolTipContent: "{label}",
   dataPoints: location_datapoints
  },
  
 ]
});

chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddiq,

It's not the indexLabel being shown over axisX but the label that's set in dataPoint. Removing label should work fine in this case.

```js
var location_datapoints = [
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 10, 0), y: 4, indexLabel: "Gold Coast", indexLabelOrientation: "vertical" },
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 11, 0), y: 4, indexLabel: "Mount Tambrine", indexLabelOrientation: "vertical" }
];
var workrest_datapoints = [
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 10, 0), y: 2, label: "Work" },
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 11, 0), y: 1, label: "Rest" }
];
   //console.log(location_datapoints);
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 exportEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "Driver Work Rest Data"
 },
 axisY:{ 
  title: "Work or Rest",
  includeZero: false,
  interval: 1,
  labelFormatter: function ( e ) {
   var ret;
   switch(e.value){
    case 1:
     ret = "Rest";
     break;
    case 2:
     ret = "Work";
     break;
    case 3:
     ret = "2-up";
     break;
    case 4:
     ret = "Location";
     break;
    case 5:
     ret = "Comments";
     break;
    case 6:
     ret = "Annotations"
     break;
    default:
     ret = '';
   }
            return ret;  
        }
 },
 axisX: {
   //interval: 1,
   intervalType: "hour",
   //valueFormatString: "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"
   },
 data: [
 
  {
   type: "bubble",
   //toolTipContent: "{label}",
   dataPoints: location_datapoints
  },
  
 ]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: Thanks, @Vishwas. I misunderstood the concept of 'label'. I have used 'name' instead in my chart now. For reference, I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the concept of 'label'. To show a proper tooltip content I used 'label' but the usage of it is different. I have used 'name' to show proper tooltip content now. This is not making any trouble and I hope this would be the right option.

For reference, I have added my code in a snippet here.

```js
var location_datapoints = [
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 10, 0), y: 4, indexLabel: "Gold Coast", indexLabelOrientation: "vertical" },
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 11, 0), y: 4, indexLabel: "Mount Tambrine", indexLabelOrientation: "vertical" }
];
var workrest_datapoints = [
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 10, 10), y: 2, name: 'Work' },
 { x: new Date(2018, 10, 18, 11, 10), y: 1, name: 'Rest' }
];
window.onload = function () {
   //console.log(location_datapoints);
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 exportEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "Driver Work Rest Data"
 },
 axisY:{ 
  title: "Work or Rest",
  includeZero: false,
  interval: 1,
  labelFormatter: function ( e ) {
   var ret;
   switch(e.value){
    case 1:
     ret = "Rest";
     break;
    case 2:
     ret = "Work";
     break;
    case 3:
     ret = "2-up";
     break;
    case 4:
     ret = "Location";
     break;
    case 5:
     ret = "Comments";
     break;
    case 6:
     ret = "Annotations"
     break;
    default:
     ret = '';
   }
            return ret;  
        }
 },
 axisX: {
   //interval: 1,
   intervalType: "hour",
   //valueFormatString: "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss"
   },
 data: [
 
  {
   type: "bubble",
   //toolTipContent: "{label}",
   dataPoints: location_datapoints
  },
  {
   type: "stepLine",
   toolTipContent: '{name}',
   dataPoints: workrest_datapoints
  }
  
 ]
});

chart.render();
}
```

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```